# Upload CSV javascript object to AWS S3 using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, backend

In my nodejs server.js file, this is what I have:

```
router.post('/submission', (req, res) => {
  let data_filtered = req.body.data
})
```

After users submit a csv, I am able to get it in my back end. Here, the format of `data_filtered` is:

```
var data_filtered = [
    {
        "Country": "Nigeria",
        "Population": "200m",
        "Continent": "Africa",
        "Official Language(s)": "English"
    },
    {
        "Country": "India",
        "Population": "1b",
        "Continent": "Asia",
        "Official Language(s)": "Hindi, English"
    }]
```

I am curious: how to upload this information to AWS S3 as a csv file? Any help will be useful! e.g. tutorials etc.

Comment: If your users are simply uploading a CSV file that your backend doesn't have to process/transform then you could potentially direct your client to upload that CSV direct to S3 via an S3 pre-signed URL.

Comment: Good point @jarmod. The issue is we are actually pre-processing users' csv before uploading them. So what I do is: I essentially use the front end js to manipulate the uploaded csv and send it back to the server side so that we can upload to S3 there

Comment: OK, but if all pre-processing of the CSV happens client-side then the client is in possession of the final CSV content so the client could write this directly to S3, via pre-signed URL that is vended by the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide your task to 2 steps.

Step 1: Converting json to csv and storing in a file.

To accomplish this step you can use a module like [json2csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv) and store the output into a file.

Step 2: Use aws-sdk to move the file to upload to S3

To accomplish this step you can [@aws-sdk/client-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-s3) module to upload your file to S3.

Comment: Just want to clarify, the objective of Step 1 is to save a converted CSV file inside the root directory (or some other places) right?

Comment: Not necessarily. I think the s3 API accepts multipart data. in that case, you can directly prepare FormData without actually saving the file to storage.